# Non-scrolling header in scrolling DrawerLayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a TextView that I am using as a header within a DrawerLayout. However, the TextView scrolls in with the rest of the menu items. I only want the menu items to scroll in.

Is there any way to only make specific items scroll in?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main Screen -->
    <RelativeLayout
        <!-- Stuff -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Header that I don't want to scroll in -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerOverview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/green"

            android:text="@string/overview"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <!-- Menu Items -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: That `<TextView>` won't scroll with the `<ListView>`. Are you sure you're looking at the right thing? Have you added a header to the `ListView` in code?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the viewGroup within a scrollView which you want to set for scrolling. Put the Header TextView out of scrollView.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Header that I don't want to scroll in -->
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerOverview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="@string/overview"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <!-- Menu Items -->
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
   />

</LinearLayout>
```